# How to solve SQL Error (1055): Expression #7 of Select list is not in group by

Tags: mysql

> SQL Error (1055): Expression #7 of Select list is not in group by Clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test_db.pid.product_id' which is not Functionally dependent on columns in group by clause; this is incomplete with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

```
SELECT pro.name AS product_name,pro.id AS product_id,pro.model AS product_model,bnd.name AS brand_name,sub_cat.name AS sub_category_name,cat.name AS category_name,
IFNULL(sum(pid.quantity)-(
                  SELECT sum(pbd.quantity)
                           from product_bill_details AS pbd
                           WHERE pbd.product_id=pid.product_id
                           GROUP BY pbd.product_id),SUM(pid.quantity))  AS quantity
FROM product_issue_details AS pid
LEFT JOIN product_issue_masters AS pim on pid.product_issue_master_id=pim.id
LEFT JOIN products AS pro ON pro.id=pid.product_id
LEFT JOIN brands AS bnd ON pro.brand_id=bnd.id
LEFT JOIN sub_categories AS sub_cat on sub_cat.id=bnd.sub_category_id
LEFT JOIN categories AS cat ON cat.id=sub_cat.category_id
WHERE pim.project_id=1
GROUP BY pro.id,pro.name,pro.model,bnd.name,cat.name,sub_cat.name
```

Comment: For a slight expansion on the error review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

if you're using PHPMyadmin click on Server:servername in top header, then click Variables, after that search for sql_mode and then click edit and remove the very 1st value ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY and save it.
This solution works as long as you don't log out.

And for MySQL workbench click on Server and then click Status and System variables, after that click on System variables and search for sql_mode and remove ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: You won't get the same mistake If the rest of your query is okay

```
SELECT pro.name AS product_name,pro.id AS product_id,pro.model AS product_model,bnd.name AS brand_name,sub_cat.name AS sub_category_name,cat.name AS category_name,
IFNULL(sum(pid.quantity)-(
                  SELECT sum(pbd.quantity)
                           from product_bill_details AS pbd
                           WHERE pbd.product_id=pid.product_id
                           GROUP BY pbd.product_id),SUM(pid.quantity))  AS quantity
FROM product_issue_details AS pid
LEFT JOIN product_issue_masters AS pim on pid.product_issue_master_id=pim.id
LEFT JOIN products AS pro ON pro.id=pid.product_id
LEFT JOIN brands AS bnd ON pro.brand_id=bnd.id
LEFT JOIN sub_categories AS sub_cat on sub_cat.id=bnd.sub_category_id
LEFT JOIN categories AS cat ON cat.id=sub_cat.category_id
WHERE pim.project_id=1
GROUP BY product_id,product_name,product_model,brand_name,category_name,sub_category_name
```

Comment: Thanks man Its showing the data  with an message "column 'product_id' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: @JulanMohajan put the table name in front of the product id column : Tablename.product_id

Comment: @JulanMohajan Nice to hear it. 